# PDO Double LIKE with Params

Tags: mysql, pdo, parameters, sql-like

I'm executing a query with PDO that doesn't retrieve any result via PHP but works in phpMyAdmin.
I'm sure about the connections setting as it's not the first query of my script and the other ones work fine.
Here the PHP code :

```
        $retour = array();
        $filters = array();
        $filters['media_type'] = 'mytype';
        $filters['libelle'] = 'sometext';
        $start = 0;
        $count = 9;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".DB_PROD_PREFIX.$this->table." t ";
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN ".DB_PROD_PREFIX.$this->table."_lang l ON t.id = l.id AND l.langue = :langue";
        $sql .= " WHERE 1";
        if (count($filter)>0){
            foreach($filter as $field => $value){
                $sql .= " AND ".$field." LIKE :".$field;
            }
        }
        $sql .= ($order!='' ? " ORDER BY ".$order : '');
        $sql .= ($count != '' ? " LIMIT ".($start != ''?':start':'0').", :count" : '');

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        if($start != '') $stmt->bindParam('start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if($count != '') $stmt->bindParam('count', $count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if ($langue != '') $stmt->bindParam('langue', $langue);

        if (count($filter)>0){
            foreach($filter as $field => $value) {
                $f = '%'.$value.'%';
                $stmt->bindParam($field, $f, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        echo $stmt->queryString.print_r($filter, true);

        if (!$stmt->execute()) echo $stmt->errorInfo();
        $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($res as $id => $row){
            $retour[]=$row;
        }
        return $retour;
```

If I unset one of the 2 keys of $filter array, the query work fine.
Here is the SQL generated :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t  
LEFT JOIN table1_lang l ON t.id = l.id AND l.langue = :langue 

WHERE 1 
AND media_type LIKE :media_type 
AND libelle LIKE :libelle 

ORDER BY position LIMIT :start, :count
```

Thanks for your help!

Pierre M.

Comment: What are the values of those parameters at runtime? Have you tested with those *exact* values in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The parameters are : Array ( [media_type] => '%image%' [libelle] => '%funn%' )
langue : fr
start : 0
count : 9. When I execute in phpMyadmin with those, it works :/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work better but thanks for the tip!
Here is a piece of code managing the LIKE parameters that works :

```
$media_type = '%'.$filter['media_type'].'%';
$stmt->bindParam('media_type', $media_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$libelle = '%'.$filter['libelle'].'%';
$stmt->bindParam('libelle', $libelle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Why doing the same with a foreach on the array doesn't work ?

```
if (count($filter)>0){
    foreach($filter as $field => $value) {
        $value = "%$value%";
        $stmt->bindParam($field, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
```

Comment: And like I said, when $filter has only 1 key/value, the query works ! :/